# Div sobrepor a outra

Tags: css

Colegas.

Estou querendo colocar um texto sobre a uma div, porém conforme altero o tamanho da div, o texto diminui e acaba quebrando. Vejam a imagem:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

O código que estou usando é esse:

```
<div style=\"width: 300px; height: 20px; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000\">
   <div style=\"position: absolute; width: ".$porcentagem."%; height: 19px; line-height:17px; background-color: #F00;\">
      <div style='position: relative'>Estoque final (".$porcentagem."%)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Seguindo a sua linha de raciocínio, coloquei um `position: absolute` e um `width: 300px` na div que contém o texto com a porcentagem.
Também alterei o `position: absolute` que estava na div que controla a cor para `position: relative`, assim a cor não ultrapassa o limite da div quando o valor for 100%.

```
<div style="width: 300px; height: 20px; background-color: #FFF; border: 1px solid #000">
    <div style="position: relative; width: ".$porcentagem."%; height: 20px; line-height:20px; background-color: #F00;">
        <div style='position: absolute; width:300px;'>Estoque final (".$porcentagem."%)</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Obrigado a todos!

Answer (score 1):

Resolvi seu problema colocando a div do texto com `position: absolute;` e definindo a largura dela com `300px` (tamanho da div pai).

Deixei um exemplo aqui no [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/xzjzq89d/2/) pra você ver.

```
 <div style='position: absolute; width: 300px'>Estoque final (44%)</div>
```